# Proving that $H^1(X,\mathcal{Hom}(\mathcal{G},\mathcal{E})) \cong \text{Ext}^1(\mathcal{G},\mathcal{E})$ holds for locally free sheaves

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, sheaf-cohomology

The following passage is from a thesis I'm reading:

> Suppose we have a short exact sequence of vector bundles $$0 \to \mathcal{E} \to \mathcal{F}\to \mathcal{G} \to 0.$$ Since these sheaves are locally free, there is an open affine cover $\{U_\alpha\}$ on which the restricted sequence does split, so let us choose a collection of splittings $\{f_\alpha : \mathcal{G}\vert_{U_\alpha} \to \mathcal{F}\vert_{U_\alpha} \}$. On overlaps, we have two splittings and we see that their differences $f_{\alpha\beta} ∶= f_\alpha - f_\beta$ have image in $\mathcal{E}\vert_{U_\alpha \cap U_\beta}$, and satisfy a cocycle condition, and in particular the $\{f_{αβ}\}$ form a Cech $1$-cocycle for the sheaf $\mathcal{Hom}(\mathcal{G},\mathcal{F})$ with respect to the cover $\{U_\alpha\}$, and hence define an element of $$H^1(X,\mathcal{Hom}(\mathcal{G},\mathcal{E})) \cong \text{Ext}^1(\mathcal{G},\mathcal{E}).$$

I tried searching for this last isomorphism $H^1(X,\mathcal{Hom}(\mathcal{G},\mathcal{E})) \cong \text{Ext}^1(\mathcal{G},\mathcal{E})$ all around and I could not find it anywhere. There was a mention of it in Le Potier J - Lectures on vector bundles in which the author states that this holds for locally free sheaves which in this instance we have since $\mathcal{E}, \mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are the sheaves corresponding to vector bundles, but there is no proof for this.

If someone here happens to know a resource in which this is proved or knows how to construct a proof, I  would gladly appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

This isomorphism holds for any degree of cohomology and it only requires that the first sheaf $\mathcal{G}$ is locally free. This relies on the fact that $\mathcal{H}om(\mathcal{G},-)$ is exact. There are two strategies for seeing this isomorphism:

Universal delta functors:

to show that $H^i(X, \mathcal{H}om(\mathcal{G}, -))$ and $\mathrm{Ext}^i(\mathcal{G}, -)$ are equal as functors, it suffices to show that both are universal delta functors and that the $i = 0$ terms are naturally isomorphic.

Indeed, $H^0(\mathcal{H}om(\mathcal{G},-)) = \mathrm{Hom}(\mathcal{G}, -)$ holds basically by definition. The Exts form a universal delta functor basically by definition. To check that $H^i(X, \mathcal{H}om(\mathcal{G}, -))$ form a universal delta functor, we need to show that it sends short exact to long exact sequences and that the higher terms are zero when evaluated on injective objects. Since $H^i$ send short exact sequences to long exact sequences, it suffices to show that $\mathcal{H}om(\mathcal{G}, -)$ is exact. This is true when $\mathcal{G}$ is locally free. Furthermore, if $\mathcal{I}$ is injective then $\mathcal{H}om(\mathcal{G}, \mathcal{I})$ has no higher cohomology (hint: show it is flasque).

Spectral sequences:

In general, there is a local-to-global ext spectral sequence,

$$ E_2^{p,q} = H^p(\mathcal{E}xt^q(\mathcal{G}, \mathcal{F})) \implies \mathrm{Ext}^{p+q}(\mathcal{G}, \mathcal{F}) $$

therefore your claim follows from the degeneration of this spectral sequence at $E_2$ because the higher ext sheaves $\mathcal{E}xt^q(\mathcal{G}, -)$ are zero since $\mathcal{G}$ is locally free and hence $\mathcal{H}om(\mathcal{G},-)$ is exact as we saw before.

Comment: Thank you, I need to go back and read about these notions on delta functors before I understand your answer thoroughly. I was kinda hoping that I could have done this using injective resolution for $\mathcal{F}$. @ben-c